# General GUI Development: Acceptable tooltip string length?

Tags: matlab, user-interface, tooltip

I'm putting the finishing touches on a GUIDE (MATLAB) developed GUI. I wanted to add tooltip strings to help the user but I don't want to overwhelm the user. Here are some examples of tootip strings that I have so far:

These are tooltip strings for 4 radio buttons that I have in a radio-group panel.

> Apply annotation to highlighted region of the selected electrode pair
>
> Apply annotation to entire data range of selected electrode pair
>
> Apply annotation to entire data-set of selected lead (6 electrode
> pairs)
>
> Apply annotation to entire data-set for both leads (12 electrode
> pairs)

This is the tooltip string for a toolbar push button

> Press to start annotating. Depending on selected mode, a highlight
> tool or window will appear

Are these too long or are they an acceptable length? Currently they convey all the information that I need to convey to the user. If these are too long, what could I do to shorten them?

Bonus question: Is there a general short-hand that is used for these types of user "hints" or "tips"?

Comment: Although you've already got an answer, you might like to ask this question on ux.stackexchange.com, where they focus on questions related to user experience and design.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I find them a little too long and convoluted. I don't know all your buttons, but if you don't have a button to specify a subrange, I would not mention 'entire range' and just omit that. Same with 'apply annotation'.

Compare:

> Apply annotation to highlighted region of the selected electrode pair.

to

> Apply to highlighted region of selected pair.

Similarly:

> Apply annotation to entire data-set of selected lead (6 electrode pairs)

to:

> Apply to selected lead of 6 electrode pairs.

Also, if the button already says 'annotate', there is no need to repeat it.

> Press to start annotating. Depending on selected mode, a highlight tool or window will appear

to:

> Show highlight tool or window to annotate

What I do generally is to keep it to the main point and rather exclude info that make it too long. If a wall of text pops up, people quickly lose interest.

If your GUI has ways to undo what you did with a button press, a curious press to see what it does is also a good thing.

Comment: This is exactly the type of advice I was looking for. Thanks!